# When should you add an event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When should I use window.onload and when should I use window.addEventListener("load", someFunction()) ?

Comment: @EliasSoares not really, OP is not asking eventlistener  vs onclick

Comment: @Nidhin Joseph it's the same answer for different events.

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* use `window.addEventListener("load", someFunction)` as the event will not be overwritten.

Using `window.onload` is subject to being overwritten by other code if you are using libraries who are not careful with your event listeners.

You can see that demonstrated below, where 3 is never displayed nor executed.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ console.log(1); });
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ console.log(2); });

window.onload = function(){ console.log(3); };
window.onload = function(){ console.log(4); };
```

In general, the same principle will apply to using other types of event listeners such as input events (click, mouse, keyboard, etc).